# Changing list of strings using python 2x

Tags: python, list, python-2.7

Is it possible to change the string list- and add letter `'y'` to each element in the list:

```
lis = ['dan','jim','roky']
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use list comprehension:

```
>>> [x + 'y' for x in lis]
['dany', 'jimy', 'rokyy']
```

Answer (score 1):

```
lis = ['dan','jim','roky']
p=map(lambda x: x+'y',lis)
```

Map is a built in function which takes first argument as the function and each of the next arguments are the iterator on which you want to iterate and update the value and returns list of result.

The lambda function is anonymous function which updates the value of elements lis.

For more info visit https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: @vaultah I have added the info. Can you update the vote ?